# Can't Find Reference to a Function in a JQuery Callback

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, scope, frontend

How do I maintain a reference to toggleSelectionInvert within my JQuery callback? Can someone explain in simple terms how the scoping works in JQuery/Javascript (why this isn't working) and how I can get it to work?

The goal is to have the page scroll to anchor tags when a button is clicked and then after the scroll swap a class to trigger a css colour animation.

Thanks!

```
jQuery(function($){

$('a[href*="#"]')
  .not('[href="#"]')
  .not('[href="#0"]')
  .click(function(event) {
    if (
      location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') 
      && 
      location.hostname == this.hostname
    ) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      console.log(target.id);
      if (target.length) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 500, function() {
          toggleSectionInvert();
          var $target = $(target);
          $target.focus();
          if ($target.is(":focus")) {
            return false;
          } else {
            $target.attr('tabindex','-1');
            $target.focus();
          };
        });
      }
    }
    });

  let toggleSectionInvert = () =>{
    var arr = $( ".front_page_section" ).toArray();
    
    arr.forEach((frontPageSection) => {
      $(frontPageSection).toggleClass('invert');
    });
  }

});
```

Te

Comment: Please make a [mcve] - it is not clear WHAT you want to keep a reference to where. I would expect to see this code `let toggleSectionInvert = () =>{ $( ".front_page_section" ).each(function() { $(this).toggleClass('invert'); }); }`

Comment: I can try making an example a bit later (not at my machine right now), but the problem I’m having is I’m getting an undefined when I try to run toggleSelectionInvert from within my Jquery “animate” callback function. I just want to know why and how to get around the problem.

Comment: Have you tried var toggleSectionInvert = ... in place of let toggleSectionInvert ?

Comment: this worked.. thanks!